# Why is Valgrind reporting read/write errors INSIDE valid blocks?

Tags: valgrind

So given this output:

```
==80518== Invalid read of size 4
==80518==    at 0x558D: Node::ReadFolder(GFile*) (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x7B61: Worker::Export(GFile*, GArray<Node*>&) (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x8F7A: Worker::Main() (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x142D64: ThreadEntryPoint(void*) (in /Users/matthew/Code/Scribe-Branches/v2.00/Utils/ScribeRecoverMail2/build/Debug/ScribeRecoverMail2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Lgi.framework/Versions/A/Lgi)
==80518==    by 0x47E258: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==80518==    by 0x47E0DD: thread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==80518==  Address 0x1d72f590 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 72 alloc'd
==80518==    at 0x41581: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==80518==    by 0x3D5616: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==80518==    by 0x77A6: Worker::Scan(GFile*, GArray<Node*>&) (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x8F0C: Worker::Main() (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x142D64: ThreadEntryPoint(void*) (in /Users/matthew/Code/Scribe-Branches/v2.00/Utils/ScribeRecoverMail2/build/Debug/ScribeRecoverMail2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Lgi.framework/Versions/A/Lgi)
==80518==    by 0x47E258: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==80518==    by 0x47E0DD: thread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==80518== 
==80518== Invalid read of size 4
==80518==    at 0x10B70F: GFile::Read(void*, int, int) (in /Users/matthew/Code/Scribe-Branches/v2.00/Utils/ScribeRecoverMail2/build/Debug/ScribeRecoverMail2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Lgi.framework/Versions/A/Lgi)
==80518==    by 0x360E: Node::Read(GFile*, unsigned int&) (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x55CF: Node::ReadFolder(GFile*) (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x7B61: Worker::Export(GFile*, GArray<Node*>&) (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x8F7A: Worker::Main() (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x142D64: ThreadEntryPoint(void*) (in /Users/matthew/Code/Scribe-Branches/v2.00/Utils/ScribeRecoverMail2/build/Debug/ScribeRecoverMail2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Lgi.framework/Versions/A/Lgi)
==80518==    by 0x47E258: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==80518==    by 0x47E0DD: thread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==80518==  Address 0x1a198900 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 alloc'd
==80518==    at 0x41581: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==80518==    by 0x3D5616: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==80518==    by 0xDFADB: GFile::GFile() (in /Users/matthew/Code/Scribe-Branches/v2.00/Utils/ScribeRecoverMail2/build/Debug/ScribeRecoverMail2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Lgi.framework/Versions/A/Lgi)
==80518==    by 0x8E4E: Worker::Main() (in ./ScribeRecoverMail2)
==80518==    by 0x142D64: ThreadEntryPoint(void*) (in /Users/matthew/Code/Scribe-Branches/v2.00/Utils/ScribeRecoverMail2/build/Debug/ScribeRecoverMail2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Lgi.framework/Versions/A/Lgi)
==80518==    by 0x47E258: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==80518==    by 0x47E0DD: thread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
```

It seems that Valgrind is complaining about normal everyday behaviour. The blocks in question are still allocated, and the access is inside the memory blocks start and end. So why does valgrind complain?

This program does crash on windows, so I built it on Mac to valgrind it and see where things are going wrong. So far lots of these "error inside block" warnings but nothing dubious like "write to free'd memory" or anything. I'm quite confused.

PS running latest stable valgrind v3.7.0, compiled and install on the same machine as I'm running it. I have been using valgrind for a long time, and never seen this sort of message before.

Comment: How does the impl of GFile::Read look like? It seems the address refers to the target memory (GFile's buffer), while its the source data that's invalid.

Comment: Hi Frank, the impl of that function is available here: http://lgi.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lgi/trunk/src/mac/General/GFile.cpp?revision=393&view=markup

Comment: I'm seeing this same kind of valgrind failure on a Linux system: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985301/valgrind-reporting-invalid-read-entirely-within-still-allocated-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that Valgrind is complaining about normal everyday behaviour

Indeed it does, and that appears to be a bug in Mac OSX version of Valgrind.

You can try to create a small test case and report it to Valgrind developers.

You could also try [address sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) and see what it reports.

Comment: "Small test case"... well the current one has a 1gb test file :(

Comment: Actually I can probably build/run on Linux as well... that might be the end run around Mac related Valgrind bugs. I will try address sanitizer as well and see how that goes.