# valgrind reporting 'Invalid read' *entirely within still-allocated block*

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

I'm seeing a truly baffling series of error reports from Valgrind's Memcheck tool:

```
==29456== Invalid read of size 8
==29456==    at 0x4D5C90: CkIndex_Ping1::_callthr_trecv_PingMsg(CkThrCallArg*) (in /scratch/phil/charm/net-linux-x86_64-bigsim/tests/charm++/pingpong/pgm)
==29456==    by 0x503ECB: CthStartThread (libthreads-default.c:1690)
==29456==    by 0x56A08AF: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so)
==29456==  Address 0x5b09a90 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 alloc'd
==29456==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29456==    by 0x4D5C14: CkIndex_Ping1::_call_trecv_PingMsg(void*, void*) (in /scratch/phil/charm/net-linux-x86_64-bigsim/tests/charm++/pingpong/pgm)
==29456==    by 0x517D79: CkDeliverMessageFree (ck.C:593)
==29456==    by 0x5378C3: CkLocRec_local::invokeEntry(CkMigratable*, void*, int, bool) (cklocation.C:1795)
==29456==    by 0x537CA7: CkLocRec_local::deliver(CkArrayMessage*, CkDeliver_t, int) (cklocation.C:1862)
==29456==    by 0x539977: CkLocMgr::deliver(CkMessage*, CkDeliver_t, int) (cklocation.C:2834)
==29456==    by 0x51F091: CkLocMgr::deliverInline(CkMessage*) (cklocation.h:313)
==29456==    by 0x51A6EF: _processArrayEltMsg(CkCoreState*, envelope*) (ck.C:1181)
==29456==    by 0x51A8C8: _processHandler(void*, CkCoreState*) (ck.C:1266)
==29456==    by 0x4EE7EF: BgProcessMessageDefault(threadInfo*, char*) (blue.C:1339)
==29456==    by 0x5C5928: BgProcessMessageFreezeMode(threadInfo*, char*) (middle-ccs.C:165)
==29456==    by 0x4F590D: workThreadInfo::scheduler(int) (bigsim_proc.C:282)
```

Note that it's saying that the offending address is inside a *still-allocated* (i.e. not yet `free()`'d) block, and that the read size plus offset is well less than the size of the block.

This is on Ubuntu Linux 14.04, with Valgrind version `valgrind-3.10.0.SVN` (package `1:3.10~20140411-0ubuntu1`), and the code was compiled with gcc/g++ `4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04`.

I've found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10159293/90002), to which the answer was "this is a bug on Mac OS X". Am I really looking at a Valgrind bug here, or is there something else my code might have wrong?

Edit: I also found [a mailing list post](http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/29874628/) covering a similar environment - user-level threads that might be screwing with Valgrind's understanding. It doesn't seem to actually answer anything though.